# SELECT * FROM sakila.actor; where first_name =TOM?

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, mysql-workbench, sakila-database

What is correct MY SQL syntax for to get the First_name = TOM from Sakila database?
I am writing this syntax but getting wrong answer

```
SELECT * FROM sakila.actor; where first_name = TOM
```

But getting error message like below:

> 11:10:05  WHERE first_name = "TOM"    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE first_name = "TOM"' at line 1    0.000 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the semi-colon before the where clause
Use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM sakila.actor WHERE first_name = 'TOM'
```